# Bibliotecas Windows para usar em Assembly

Tags: assembly, biblioteca

Quais bibliotecas utilizo para construir uma interface gráfica do Windows, e suas respectivas funções?

Exemplo: Posso importar a biblioteca `msvcrt.dll` para usar funções de C.

Tenho alguma experiência em Assembly para código em baixo nível, mas nem tanta para construir um `.exe` que rode no Windows.

Basicamente quero saber quais bibliotecas usar para fazer uma aplicação com interface gráfica.

Conheço bem a linguagem e não preciso que me ensine, apenas falem as bibliotecas e como usá-las.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda<sup>*</sup> a [API do Windows é disponibilizada em C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Então tem que usar essas bibliotecas. Também pode consultar o [Docs em geral](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O grosso do aprendizado deverá ser em cima do que tem para C. Como disse que sabe bem Assembly não terá dificuldade em fazer as chamadas das funções passando os argumentos conforme a documentação.

Tem um [exemplo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029093/221800).

E um [tutorial usando o NASM](http://mathimaaran.angelfire.com/helloworld_tutorial.htm).

<sup>*</sup>Hoje já não é bem assim.

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Programar para a interface gráfica nativa do Windows (Win32) é um assunto bastante extenso.

Para estudar seriamente recomendo seguir um livro, como o clássico "Programming in Windows" do Charles Petzold.
([https://www.amazon.com.br/gp/product/B00JDMP71S/ref=pd_sim_351_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZBACE0VE2R00P4XB0V5Z](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JDMP71S))

Para uso casual existem inúmeros exemplos na net, basta o Google, por exemplo:
http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_1.shtm
http://winprog.org/tutorial/
http://www.relisoft.com/win32/
etc

e aqui um exemplo da própria Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx